# How to store a complete column in other df and store its index from second table to original table using panda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this.

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0     DS      4.5     Hard
1     ML      2.5     Medium
2     CS       4      Hard
```

I want to check if any column is having a duplicate value if yes then need to store the unique value of that column in another df and store its index in the original position.

Like in this case we will have output as two df like below:

df1:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0     DS      4.5      0
1     ML      2.5      1
2     CS       4       0
```

d2:

```
   Column1
0    Hard
1    Medium
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my approach would be to firstly create the dataframe containing only the unique values of `Column3`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1['Column3'].unique())
df1.columns = ['Column3']
```

Looks like this:

```
    Column3
0   Hard
1   Medium
```

Then we can replace the `Column3` values with the indices by using pandas `replace()` method:

```
df2 = df.replace(to_replace=df1.values, value=df1.index.values)
```

Output:

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3
0   DS  4.5 0
1   ML  2.5 1
2   CS  4.0 0
```